# Node.js express: Getting HTTP header before it is sent

Tags: node.js, http, express, header, content-length

I am currently making an application in Node.js, with the Express web server plug-in. I want to count the total data sent by the web server.
To do this, I need to get the 'Content-Length' field of an outgoing HTTP header. However, I need to do this right after the data is added.

If I need to alter core Express scripts, can somebody tell me which file this is contained in?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to count it, you can use a middleware for that:

```
var totalBytes = 0;
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.on('finish', function() {
    totalBytes += Number(res.get('content-length') || 0);
  });
  next();
});
```

You have to include very early in the middleware stack, before any other middleware whose contents you want to count.

Also, this doesn't count any streamed data, for which no `Content-Length` header is set.

Comment: Yes, this is whatI want to do. I am currently trying your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could add middleware to monkey-patch the response methods. It’s ugly but better than altering core Express files.

This calculates total body bytes for standard and streamed responses. Place this before any other `app.use()` directives.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.totalLength = 0;

  var realResWrite = res.write;
  res.write = function(chunk, encoding) {
    res.totalLength += chunk.length;
    realResWrite.call(res, chunk, encoding);
  };

  var realResEnd = res.end;
  res.end = function(data, encoding) {
    if (data) { res.totalLength += data.length; }
    console.log('*** body bytes sent:', res.totalLength);
    realResEnd.call(res, data, encoding);
  };

  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count it on each request then you can try below code!!!

```
var totalByte=0;
app.all('*', function(req,res, next){
    res.on('finish', function() {
        totalByte = parseInt(res.getHeader('Content-Length'), 10);
        if(isNaN(totalByte))
            totalByte = 0;
   });
    next(); 
});
```

Please remember totalByte is a global variable here and it added value on each request